# Adding key value pairs from a file to a Hashmap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, nio

I am trying to extract a key value pair from a file to a Hashmap for easier manipulation of values.

The file is in this format:

```
Activity1:3:Activity2:5:Activity3:7:
Activity4:1:
```

Each line has a maximum of 3 activities and its corresponding number.

```java
String currentPath;
Path fullPath;
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

try {
    // Obtain current directory path
    currentPath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
    // Obtain full path of data.txt
    fullPath = Paths.get(currentPath, "data.txt");
    // Check if file exists
    if (Files.exists(fullPath)) {
        // Read line by line in data.txt
        Files.lines(fullPath)
                .forEach(line -> hm.put(line.split(":")[0], line.split(":")[1]) );
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("data.txt is not found.");
    }
} catch (
        IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, only the first key:value pair is inserted into the Hashmap. 
I tried to use

```java
.map(s -> s.split(":"))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r[0], r -> r[1] ))
```

but it does not work as the `split()` output type is an Array which `toMap` doesn't accept.

**Edit:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String currentPath;
        Path filePath;
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        Pattern delimiter = Pattern.compile(":");

        try {
            // Obtain current directory path
            currentPath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
            // Obtain full path of data.txt
            filePath = Paths.get(currentPath, "data.txt");
            // Check if file exists
            if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
                // Read line by line in data.txt
                    hm = Files.lines(filePath)
                        .map(delimiter::split) // stream of multiple Array<String>
                        .flatMapToInt(a -> IntStream.range(0, a.length - 1))  // combine multiple Array<String> to a
                            // single stream, remove last Array<String>
                        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)  // obtain only even indices
                        .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a[i], a[i+1])) // a cannot be resolved. Create new Map, key is Array<String>[even], value is Array<String>[odd]
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> a)); //
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("data.txt not found.");
            }
        } catch (
                IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (String objectName : hm.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(objectName);
            System.out.println(hm.get(objectName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's take a look at why your solution does not give intended result. When you split each line around the delimiter `:` then there may be many key value pairs. But you just consider the first key value pair while omitting the rest. So this works for the last line in your example since it has only one corresponding map entry. At the same time it does not work for the first line since it has many corresponding map entries while you are treating only the first entry.

And here's my approach for solving this problem. Take each line in your file and split it around the delimiter `:`. This yields an array to each corresponding line. Since every line has a trailing `:` character, you have to skip the relevant last element in the array. Then each even indice in the array becomes the key in the map, and the immediately following odd index becomes the corresponding value. Here's how it looks.

```
private static final Pattern DELIMITER = Pattern.compile(":");
Map<String, String> activityMap = lines.map(DELIMITER::split)
    .flatMap(a -> IntStream.range(0, a.length - 1).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a[i], a[i + 1])))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a));
```

And the output looks like this:

> {Activity3=7, Activity4=1, Activity1=3, Activity2=5}

Comment: May I ask, how do I integrate the Regex code ? I am genuinely confused about the Streams. I commented my understanding in the edited code, kindly take a look.

Comment: Your `flatMapToInt` has no use here. Go through the answer given and change yours accordingly. Notice that the `filter` and `mapToObj` operators lie inside the `flatMap` operator. You can't access the array reference `a` outside of the `flatMap` operator and that's why the compiler spits out an error here. Go through the compiler errors, try to interpret them and fix them. Moreover when you declare the map use the interface type instead of the implementation like so: `Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't notice the `filter` and `MapToObj` are part of `filter`. Noted on the Map declaration as well, is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible
>   Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

This question is a good example why MRE is required and why it is so useful. 
When hard-coding the data to make an mre, you quickly realize that the problem is not related to the file:

```
    String line = "Activity1:3:Activity2:5:Activity3:7:" ;
    String[] lineAsArray = line.split(":"); 

    //lineAsArray is of the following stucture [Activity1, 3, Activity2, 5, Activity3, 7]
    //by line.split(":")[0], line.split(":")[1]) you simply add Activity1, 3
    //to get all pairs iterate over the array:
    for(int index = 0; index < lineAsArray.length ; index+=2){
        System.out.println("key = "+ lineAsArray[index]+ " value = "+ lineAsArray[index+1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

The current implementation does not cover the cases, when one line contains many key-value pairs.

## Solution

The following draft solution performs the line parsing taking into account that one line may contain many key-value pairs.

```java
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("Activity1:3:Activity2:5:Activity3:7:");
        lines.add("Activity4:1:");

        final Map<String, String> map = lines
            .stream()
            .map(Main::parseLine)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private static List<Map.Entry<String, String>> parseLine(final String line) {
        final List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        final String[] components = line.split(":");
        final int pairCount = components.length / 2;
        for (int pairNumber = 0; pairNumber < pairCount; ++pairNumber) {
            final int pairStartIndex = pairNumber * 2;
            entries.add(
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                    components[pairStartIndex],
                    components[pairStartIndex + 1]
                )
            );
        }
        return entries;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
{Activity3=7, Activity4=1, Activity1=3, Activity2=5}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {

    /Example :- File file = new File("src/abc.txt");/
    File file = new File("<absolute_file_path>");
    if(file.exists()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String data = null;
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] str = data.split(":");
            for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i += 2) {
                hashMap.put(str[i - 1], str[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hashMap);
        br.close();
    }else
        System.out.println("File not exists");

  }
}
```

And the output looks like this:

> `{Activity3=7, Activity4=1, Activity1=3, Activity2=5}`